# Sql like with without leading 0's

Tags: sql, mysql, entity-framework-core

I have a table like this

```
Id  Number (string)

1   0000231
2   00232
3   231
4   24
5   A1233
```

Ex:  I need to search by value 23 ( may vary)

**Expected Result:**

```
Id  Number

1   0000231
2   00232
3   23
```

Current Ef core search code

Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.AIN, $"{filter}%"))

This is getting only 3rd record. Table has Number column which has string. But need to eliminate leading 0's in like function.

i dont expect answer in Ef. i need Sql query to ]handle effienntly

EDIT:

Finally found solution bases on @salman Answer in EF Some one others

```
.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.AIN.TrimStart('0'), $"{filter}%")
```

Comment: Why not just `Where(c => c.AIN.EndsWith(filter)`?

Comment: I have updated my question it not always end with 23

Comment: You can add the `%` wildcard at the beginning as well, as `$"%{filter}%"`, except for one thing. Can you explain why the 5th record `A1233` is not expected in the result, as it does contain the substring `23` in there?

Comment: @SalmanA no because i need only starts with 23 not  in midle

Comment: Thanks I need similar like that I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use the [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function:

```
where trim(leading '0' from number) like  '23%'
```

An alternate would be to use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp) operator:

```
where number regexp '0*23'
```

Comment: @Ajt It's better than, say, a leading wildcard... but it's still not efficient, because calling a function like `trim()` to modify the stored values in the table breaks any chance of using indexes. If you want this to be efficient, you'll need to add a column to store the trimmed value all the time, so you can index it, and add code to the application to keep the new column up to date.

Comment: Thanks @Salman one more last question can use in  SQL lite ?

Comment: @ajt in SQLite you would use LTRIM which accepts two arguments https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ltrim

Comment: SQLite?  You tagged with MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually in mobile app I am using sql lite and in api my sql… sorry initially i thought syntax will be almost same.. but after answer received I understood will not work for both

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle this using raw MySQL, then you could try just casting the column value from text to integer:

```sql
SELECT Id, Number
FROM yourTable
WHERE CAST(Number AS UNSIGNED) = 23;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it not always end with 23 and also number it charcter.